# Angular2 Http GET always throws error

Tags: http, angular

I believe I'm just doing something wrong here, but for some reason, my http.get() request always throws an error.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
...
export class CustomClass{
  ...
  getAPI(){
    this.http.get('http://ip-api.com/json')
      .map((res: Response) => {
        res.json();
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data),
        (error) => console.error(error),
        () => console.log(this)
      );
  }
}
```

I'm under the impression that this code block should simple get the response form `http://ip-api.com/json` and then output it. However, the only result I ever get is the error response and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct, check the Network tab in the Browser developing tools and see why the http request fails.